# SQL defining duration using foreign key

Tags: sql, postgresql, datetime, timestamp

The design of the database I have at the moment, has two different tables holding information I require for a specific field inside one of the tables.

```
create table EventInfo (
  id          serial NOT NULL CHECK (id > 0),
  title       LongNameValue NOT NULL,
  startingTime  timestamp,
  duration 
  primary key (id),
  foreign key (e_id) references Event(id)
);

create table Events (
  id          serial,
  endTime  timestamp,
  primary key (id),
};
```

my question is,

is it possible to have a the `duration` field be calculated from `endTime - startingtime`? Also, how would you go about doing this? I was thinking of using `interval`. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: What database are you using? Also, please post the queries that you have tried

Comment: Why you make two tables? Based on your two tables, I think you can create one Table only, it is enough. Just add endTime to EventInfo. Any particular reason that you make two tables?

Comment: *Why* are start and end time in different tables? What does it even mean if there are two `EventInfo` rows with different start times, for a single `Events` row?

Comment: it's for an assignment, we are meant to create the database, based off the ERD design. I don't know why it's like that though =S

Comment: Putting the end time into a different table does not make any sense. With this model an Event has a single endtime but multiple start times. How do you calculate the duration if there is more than one starttime for the event?

Answer (score 1):

When you design your database you should keep in mind that only primitive normalized data should go in to tables.

When you have "calculated" data stored in tables you can fall into inconsistencies situations.

Calculated data should go into views, procedures or even at the application level.

Said that if I was you I put *endTime* in *EventInfo* table and build a view with the calculated *duration* column.

Answer (score 0):

Computed Column can only be generated from Column of same table.

Its not possible with two different table

Comment: well, *can* and *should* are different, but I hear you.  you could do this in PostgreSQL but performance would be a bit annoying.

Answer (score 0):

You can look at functions to do this.  If you:

```
CREATE FUNCTION duration("EventInfo") RETURNS interval LANGUAGE SQL AS
    $$ SELECT .... $$;
```

Then you can:

```
SELECT e.duration FROM "EventInfo" e;
```

And it will work as expected.